# yum groupinstall "Development Tools" fails

Tags: centos, yum

Running

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

on my CentOS machine fails. I get errors such as:

> http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/fedora-epel/5/i386/repodata/7665d1f4c95b91088577b351525888a460749412-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout: <urlopen error timed out>

Any workarounds / alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

This could be a transient network error. Wait a bit and try again.

Do other downloads from this site work? Try browsing 
http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/fedora-epel/5/i386/repodata/ (if this is on a command-line-only machine, use a command-line browser such as lynx, links or w3m).

Do you need to set up a proxy to access the web? Yum, like most programs, uses the `http_proxy` environment variable. If you need a proxy, put this in your `~/.profile` (and run it once in your shell so that it takes effect no) (replace the host name and port number by the right values for you):

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:3128/
```

Try other [CentOS mirrors](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30) if this particular one isn't working for you.

Comment: Actually it's a fedora-epel mirror thats failing, might pay to try with `--disablerepo='epel'`  (not worth creating a new answer for imo)

Comment: @NJ: `--disablerepo='epel'` would be worth a new answer, but since that site is working for me right now, Gaurav's problem has got to be a networking issue (either a glitch or a misconfiguration).

Answer (score 3):

If you continue to get the errors only for EPEL mirrors, try running yum with the `--disablerepo='epel'` option as a temporary workaround (i.e. `yum --disaberepo='epel' groupinstall "Development Tools"`, if it continues to happen, you may need to try and find the mirror admin and advise them that something is wrong.

Try Gilles' answer first though, this is a pure workaround.